# IE8 memory leak/performance issue when attaching too many event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer

I have a web page with a lot of list elements (close to 3000). I am attaching a click event handler for these and a hover event as well (using jquery).

```
$('li').click(function (e){
    // do processing here 
}) 

$('li').hover(function (e){
    // do processing here for hover in 
}, function (e) {
    // do processing here hover out 
})
```

On IE8, I am starting to notice some slowdown, and my initial guess is that the number of event handlers is causing a memory leak/consumption issue. This works great in Chrome, FF, IE9.

Has anyone else noticed this behavior?

I was also thinking that using jquery delegate would solve this issue, since the event handlers would live in the parent container, and not one for each list element. Something like the following-

```
$("#somecontainer").delegate('li', 'click', function () {
    //do processing for click here. 
})
```

Any insight into this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was also thinking that using jquery delegate would solve this issue,
>   since the event handlers would live in the parent container, and not
>   one for each list element.

Absolutely. Or do it [the "new" way](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#somecontainer").on("click", "li", function () {
    //do processing for click here. 
});
```

Comment: Yup, your hunch was right, and karim79 has provided the current best practice (that extra comma after "li", looks fishy, but I didn't double-check with the API).

Comment: @GregPettit - The extra comma was my typo, not some awesome new addition to the API :)

Comment: haha, OK. :-) Cheers for promoting the use of `.on()`. I see too many people still recommending `.live()` of all things!

Comment: I actually did not know a method like "on" existed. As much as I would like to use it, I am stuck to jquery 1.4.2 for a while, so I think I'll use delegate for the time being. Thanks!